# How to reject use of certain words in a form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, input

I am new to Javascript. 
I need to make an username input, then validate it.
The username entered must not be one of the elements in this array: `["admin", "administrator", "demo", "user"]` etc. The array can be longer.

I made this so far, but it works only for the 1st element in the array.

```
function arrayValidation () {
    nonoUser = ["username", "admin", "administrator", "demo"];
    valueOfInput = document.getElementById("user").value; // "user" here is id of input
    for (var i = 0; i < nonoUser.length; i++) {
        if (valueOfInput == nonoUser[i]) {
            alert("you cant use this username");
        }else {
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that in JavaScript? It's a client side language, anyone could view the source..

Comment: if your input not equals to first input it is going to else where you put return. so remove else block

Comment: @Mathijs Flietstra is correct – you should validate this on the server-side as a minimum, and add javascript validation as a nice-to-have. Relying on javascript validation for this could be disastrous!

Comment: Since you are new to JS, this is just as a good-to-know fact: Whatever or however you write JavaScript, it's always compiled and ran at the client side. This means that no matter what precautions you try to take, everyone can easily read all the code you write -including that array of usernames. That's one of the many reasons @MathijsFlietstra has a few thumbs-up for his comment.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I am doing this only for exercise purposes. Thanks again.

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo - *"it's always compiled and run at the client side"* is [an overstatement](http://nodejs.org/), but when the sample code includes `document.getElementById` it's fairly safe to assume it is going to be run in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function arrayValidation () {
    nonoUser = ["username", "admin", "administrator", "demo"];
    valueOfInput = document.getElementById("user").value; // "user" here is id of input
    var isValid = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < nonoUser.length && isValid; i++) {
        if (valueOfInput == nonoUser[i]) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    if (isValid) {
        // Username is valid
    }else{
        // Username is invalid
    }
}
```

However, you should never trust data that's sent to the server (Validate server-side as well)
It's trivial to change the js as a user.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
document.getElementById("user").onkeyup = function(){
    var nonoUser = ["username", "admin", "administrator", "demo"];
    nonoUser.indexOf(this.value) === -1 ? false : this.value = '';
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Le2xC/

I also hope you're validating this server-side as well, otherwise users will still be able to use your "nono" usernames.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add return false; to the code section with the alert, not the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The comments here should help you to see why your code isn't working as you expect:

```
// Your original code:

function arrayValidation () {
    nonoUser = ["username", "admin", "administrator", "demo"];
    valueOfInput = document.getElementById("user").value; // "user" here is id of input
    for (var i = 0; i < nonoUser.length; i++) {
        if (valueOfInput == nonoUser[i]) {
            alert("you cant use this username");
        } else {

            // Using return here is the problem. 
            // This else block will run if a valid username was entered.
            // The return statement stops execution of the function, thus ending the loop. 
            // So if the loop passes the test the first time, this return 
            // statement will stop the loop and function from completing 
            // the checks against the other keywords. 

            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

This is your code modified to work as you expect:

```
function arrayValidation () {
    nonoUser = ["username", "admin", "administrator", "demo"];
    valueOfInput = document.getElementById("user").value; // "user" here is id of input
    for (var i = 0; i < nonoUser.length; i++) {
        if (valueOfInput == nonoUser[i]) {
            alert("you cant use this username");

            // We can end the function check return here.
            // There's no point checking the others, as we've found an invalid one. 

            return false; // Return a meaningful result
        }

        // No need for an else statement either.

    }
}
```

As many have pointed out, client side validation should be considered an optional extra, and server-side validation as essential.